# ModuleNotFoundError on own folder

Tags: python

I have this folder structure:

```
main.py
utils
--forms.py
```

and am now trying in main.py to import something from forms.py with this:

`from utils.forms import search_form`

but I am getting this Exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kofi/Desktop/projects/groundtruth_auswertung/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utils.forms import search_form
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.forms'; 'utils' is not a package
```

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: try adding an empty `__init__.py` file under utils folder

Comment: I think this is helpful in understanding python's slightly complicated import system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time You probably can figure out why you got your error in this link.

Answer (score 1):

for me its working and on linux too.

```sh
 [~/Alexzander__/programming/python3/learning/modulenotfounderror]
❱  tree
 .
├──  main.py
└──  utils
   └──  forms.py


 [~/Alexzander__/programming/python3/learning/modulenotfounderror]
❱  ca main.py

from utils.forms import search_form

print("success")%                                                                      

 [~/Alexzander__/programming/python3/learning/modulenotfounderror]
❱  python main.py
success
```

Comment: I just tried to make another folder and there it works, it seems to have a problem with the folder name `utils` for whatever reason :/ Tho I can't tell why.
should I update the question to show more code?

Comment: maybe there is a python module somewhere that is called `utils.py` and thats why you get an error

Comment: I now changed the name to util and that works, still weird tho

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `__init__.py` in the `utils` folder, which allows the folder to be used as a package. (The file doesn't have to have anything inside)

This is only necessary on python 2 though, in python 3 it works automatically without the need for such file.